# Inserting a concatenated value into a table

Tags: mysql, sql

With MYSQL, I can calculate the time difference and get it as a concatenated output.
I am using queries sourced from [here.](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-mysql/)

```
WITH difference_in_seconds AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    departure,
    arrival,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, departure, arrival) AS seconds
  FROM travel
),
 
differences AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    departure,
    arrival,
    seconds,
    MOD(seconds, 60) AS seconds_part,
    MOD(seconds, 3600) AS minutes_part,
    MOD(seconds, 3600 * 24) AS hours_part
  FROM difference_in_seconds
)
 
SELECT
id,
departure,
arrival,
CONCAT(
  FLOOR(seconds / 3600 / 24), ' days ',
  FLOOR(hours_part / 3600), ' hours ',
  FLOOR(minutes_part / 60), ' minutes ',
  seconds_part, ' seconds'
) AS difference
FROM differences;
```

My output is something like this:

```
id  departure           arrival             difference
1   2018-03-25 12:00:00 2018-04-05 07:30:00 10 days 19 hours 30 minutes 0 seconds
```

What I would like to do is to get hold of the concatenated string of "difference" and update/insert into another table. In the other table, I have a column called "time_difference" so I have tried to use the update query. I also have a condition set where it should update only to the relevant user profile.

```
    UPDATE airport_database.user
    SET time_difference = (SELECT
  id,
  departure,
  arrival,
  CONCAT(
    FLOOR(seconds / 3600 / 24), ' days ',
    FLOOR(hours_part / 3600), ' hours ',
    FLOOR(minutes_part / 60), ' minutes ',
    seconds_part, ' seconds'
  ) AS difference
FROM differences)
    WHERE name = "Sir";
```

However, I am getting

> Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Therefore I also tried to get the concatenated value through:

```
UPDATE airport_database.user
        SET time_difference = (difference)
        WHERE name = "Sir";
```

And I get

> Error #1054 - Unknown column of 'difference' in 'Field List'.

I would like to know why my concatenated string column is unable to be detected by MYSQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the reason to obtain the difference in seconds and then format the result to time in 2nd CTE whereas you may use TIMEDIFF() and obtain the difference in needed form with one step?

Comment: *And I get Error #1241* You must use not correlated subquery in your UPDATE but multiple-table UPDATE syntax. `UPDATE destination_table JOIN (your subquery) ON (joining condition) SET ...`.

Comment: @Akina I would like to use the difference in seconds to calculate the remainders of seconds, which can calculate minutes and later hour to get the difference. After which it will be displayed in terms of days, hours, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DEMO.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE src (id INT, departure DATETIME, arrival DATETIME);
> INSERT INTO src VALUES (1, '2018-03-25 12:00:00', '2018-04-05 07:30:00');
> CREATE TABLE dst (id INT, departure DATETIME, arrival DATETIME, verbal_diff VARCHAR(255));
> INSERT INTO dst SELECT *, NULL FROM src;
> SELECT * FROM dst;
> ```
>
> | id | departure | arrival | verbal_diff |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2018-03-25 12:00:00 | 2018-04-05 07:30:00 | *null* |

> ```
> UPDATE dst
> JOIN (SELECT id,
>              CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, departure, arrival),
>                     DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(arrival, departure), ' days %H hours %i minutes %s seconds')) difference
>       FROM src) data USING (id)
> SET dst.verbal_diff = data.difference;
>
> SELECT * FROM dst;
> ```
>
> | id | departure | arrival | verbal_diff |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2018-03-25 12:00:00 | 2018-04-05 07:30:00 | 10 days 19 hours 30 minutes 00 seconds |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=501fb33253f079cf999a102fa1219d5a)*

See [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), Multiple-table syntax.